# structure of the website/Separating html and php code

Tags: php, html

The question is easy how to separate the php and html code on the website page?

For an example we have the page

```
    ...
  <div>
        <div id="form_place">
            ... /*some html code*/
        </div>  
    </div>
    ...
```

So, in the block "form_place" there is a form which php code must fill up something,
    so the most people will write something like that:

```
...
<div>
    <div id="form_place">
        ... /*some html code of forms*/
        <?php echo $var1; ?>
        /*some html code of forms*/
        <?php echo $var2; ?>
        /*some html code of forms*/...
    </div>  
</div>
...
```

However the right way as I understand correctly is to separate the php and html code.
So now is a question how to separate it?
Divide the html code on blocks  and then include them in order is not a variant because if we will have a millions of variables then we will need to divide the HTMl page on million part and include them which will significant increase the load time.

So what I have in mind is just php load the full html page and put variables in the place where it is suppose to be. But I don't know how to realize it.

I just need to know what usually people do in those situations. Question is general and the answer was received. 
Mr. *GolezTrol* I don't ask tutorial just the principle of realization.

Comment: Don't try to reinvent the wheel, just use one of the existing templating engines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: "yes and no"...

You are right that it is good style to separate logic and visualization.

However what you show in your example is *not* a mix of logic and visualization. That is because those php snippets only inject some passive data into the markup. That is absolutely fine, actually there is no way around using some dynamic component in a template based approach. What irritates here simply is that php is not only the language used for the applications logic, but also as dynamic component inside your template. But still those are two different things. So in my eyes the above is generally OK, provided two rules are kept:

1. the php usage inside such a template should be limited to simply conditions, loops and variable references. Stuff you need to generated the markup including tables, breakcrumbs and the like. No complex function calls should be done though, no storage access, nothing.
2. the data used for that purpose should have been specially prepared for usage inside the template and is typically handed over inside a container.

*Rule 2. is maybe something where you should take a closer look at your example: question is where those variables come from. They certainly should not be some global variables. Instead you should use some container (an object or an array) holding the data used to render your template.*

---

In general all this points towards the wide spread and well proven MVC approach: it indeed strictly separates logic and visualization. Logic is mostly done in the controllers and the model (the C and M in MVC), while the visualization is done in the views (templates) (the V in MVC).

Answer (score 1):

Don't think of it as "separating PHP from HTML".  Those are just tools.  Think of it as "separating logic from interface".  You want to arrange your code such that *logical concerns* are separated, not focus on arbitrary languages and technologies.

There's nothing inherently wrong with this:

```
<div>
    <div id="form_place">
        ... /*some html code of forms*/
        <?php echo $var1; ?>
        /*some html code of forms*/
        <?php echo $var2; ?>
        /*some html code of forms*/...
    </div>  
</div>
```

All this PHP code does is emit values onto the page.  This is purely a user interface concern.  You can make use of various tempting engines to accomplish this task in different ways, but the concept is the same.  The code above is entirely a user interface and has no other concerns aside from that.

What you want to **avoid** is something more like this:

```
<div>
    <div id="form_place">

        <?php
            // a bunch of database interactions to get a result
        ?>

        ... /*some html code of forms*/
        <?php echo $var1; ?>

        <?php
            // a bunch of calculations to transform results
        ?>

        /*some html code of forms*/
        <?php echo $var2; ?>
        /*some html code of forms*/...
    </div>  
</div>
```

This is putting database interactions and business logic in the middle of your user interface, which you want to avoid.

Don't focus so much on separating the technologies, focus on separating the concerns.  Technologies often overlap across concerns, but the concerns shouldn't overlap across each other.